# Trying to reset counter results to zero by clicking button in Python

Tags: python, kivy

I made a game with `python 3.9.5`, `kivy 2.0.0rc4` and `kivymd 0.104.2`. I've made counter. It's adding one after "check" button is pressed. Game works smoothly but I want to reset this counter results to zero by clicking "back" button. Because, when I get back to it, I want to start the game from the top. Technically restart the game. Here's my `python` code:

```
class Begin(MDFloatLayout):

    def back_on(self):
        self.ids.to_back.source = 'icons/back_pressed.png'
        click = SoundLoader.load('sounds/clickb_effect.wav')
        if click:
            click.play()

    def back_off(self):
        self.ids.to_back.source = 'icons/back.png'
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Second'

    def update_score(self, score_one):
        self.ids.score_one.text = score_one

class Begin1After(MDFloatLayout):
    count = -1
    my_text = StringProperty("0")

    def check_on(self):
        self.ids.to_check.source = 'icons/check_pressed.png'
        correct = SoundLoader.load('sounds/correct.wav')
        if correct:
            correct.play()

    def check_off(self, *args):
        self.ids.to_check.source = 'icons/check.png'
        self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        begin = self.my_text = str(self.count)
        myapp.begin.update_score(begin)
```

And here's my `kivy/kivymd` code:

```
<Begin>:

    Label:
        id: score_one
        text: "0"
        color: 0, 1, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {'x': -.22, 'y': .33}
        font_size: 80
        font_name: 'CursedTimerUlil-Aznm'

    Button:
        size_hint: .1, .11
        pos_hint: {'x': .01, 'y': .9}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        on_press: root.back_on()
        on_release: root.back_off()

        Image:
            id: to_back
            source: "icons/back.png"
            allow_stretch: True
            allow_ratio: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size: 160, 160
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

<Begin1After>:

    Label:
        text: root.my_text
        pos_hint: {'x': .0, 'y': .35}
        font_size: 100
        bold: True
        color: 0, 20, 0, 1

    Button:
        size_hint: .19, .11
        pos_hint: {'x': .76, 'y': .14}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        on_press: root.check_on()
        on_release: root.check_off()

        Image:
            id: to_check
            source: "icons/check.png"
            allow_stretch: True
            allow_ratio: True
            keep_ratio: True
            size: 170, 170
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day.

### 1. Reset Function

Create a 'reset' method to contain all the code to revert your game as you might have other attributes to change as well.

### 2. Callback Method

Create a callback function for your 'back' button. This callback might check for a condition before it calls the 'reset' method. i,e

`if game_won: reset()`